# Jquery ajax call is not working.. Please provide me the solution

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-4.5

//When focusout event is working, tested with alert.. but ajax call is not working and my aspx.cs method also not firing.. Please solve this issue.
//This is my aspx page jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var elem = document.getElementById('<%=txtProduct.ClientID %>');

        $(elem).focusout(function () {
            myF($(this).val());
        });

        function myF(value) {
            var fist = value.split(' ( ', 1);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Invoice.aspx/getProductDetails',                   
                data: "{'strCode':'" + fist + "'}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d.toString());
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

//Server side code

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string getProductDetails(string strCode)
    {
        List<string> companyInfo = new List<string>();
        companyInfo.Add(HttpContext.Current.Cache[Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]) + "CompanyID"].ToString());
        companyInfo.Add(strCode);
        List<string> price = Database.MasterDB.getProductInfo(companyInfo);
        if (price.Count > 0)
            return price[0].ToString();
        else
            return "000";
    }
```

Comment: you might need an `[HttpPost]` attribute

Comment: This is not MVC, only ASP.Net Web Application, Please suggest where to add [HttpPost]

Comment: Are you getting any kind of response in the browser console?  It should show you that it's made the ajax call and tell you what kind of response you got.

Comment: Use `[WebMethod]` or `[HttpPost]` (as Jonesy suggested) instead of `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]`. You can also try to use `error: function(response)` instead of `failure: function (response)`

Comment: try to add this to allow it calling from ajax: [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] before the class that contains the service

Comment: @Archer : My console error is

ReferenceError: value is not defined

var fist = value.split(' ( ', 1);

Comment: 'error:function(response)' returning the error 'function (){if(l){var t=l.length;(function i(t){x.each(t,function(t,n){var r=x.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||l.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=l.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}'

Comment: console error: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: This same above code is working in new web application.. but in my application this is not working.. I am not using any other jquery any where.. But used ajax toolkit. How to solve this issue. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Session thing inside web method, that might be giving null values or blank values. This is because you have not enabled session for webmethod.

Like this - `[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]`.

[Read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.enablesession(v=vs.90).aspx)